# Meaning of "she didn't know what to think"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> some weeks later, the door of Esmeralda’s
>   cell cracked open. A shaft of blinding light
>   entered from the world outside. Then the
>   door closed again. A human form, holding a
>   lantern, stood before her.
>   “Who are you?” she asked.
>   “A priest,” was the simple answer.
>   The sound of that familiar voice made her
>   tremble. She knew immediately that her
>   visitor was Claude Frollo.
>   “Are you ready?” he asked.
>   “For what?”
>   “To die. Your execution will be tomorrow.”
>   Esmeralda clenched her pale, thin fingers.
>   “Why have you done this?” she asked sadly.
>   “What have I ever done to harm you? Why
>   should you hate me so?”
>   “But I love you!” Frollo exclaimed.
>   Her tears suddenly stopped. In spite of her
>   fear, she stared at him in confusion. A drop of
>   cold water fell upon her cheek. **She didn’t
>   know what to think.**

Dose it mean: she didn't know what is wronge or right?

Or dose it mean:she didn't know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

It expresses a state of confusion, uncertainty or mixed emotion so intense as to impede thought. It *might*, in any given case, be confusion over right and wrong, but I would say that it is not usually so.

In this case, a man is declaring his love for her while ordering or cooperating in her death. She is getting conflicting information, and doesn't know what to make of it - at least initially.

If a person doesn't know what to think, they will usually not know what to do - thought it might also occur in cases where there is no question of doing anything. But a person can know what to think, or it might be put as what *they* think, while still not knowing what to do. It is even true that there will be cases where a person knows what they must do, but doesn't know what to think. I would say it is usually about dealing with conflicting information, emotions or evidence.